# Session Expiration Issue Asp.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing session expiring issue in my ASP.NET Web Forms application. The session is timing out randomly. After 5 to 10 minutes(not exact time but happening randomly) there is no any explicit session. Timeout declaration elsewhere in the code. Given below are settings I have defined in Web.Config file. Any help is much appreciated

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="350000" enableVersionHeader="false"
             maxQueryStringLength="3584" executionTimeout="180000"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

Comment: try <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" cookieless="true"></sessionState>

Comment: check sessionstate more options https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: check your IIS idle time settings.